# Both Control keys not working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

so .. suddenly both of my control keys stopped working. The machine is an Acer Aspire 5950G laptop running Windows 7.

Things I've already tried:

1. Pressing ctrl + alt + fn doesn't do anything,
2. On-screen keyboard works flawlessly,
3. Booting in safe mode still preserves the issue,
4. Taking off keycaps showed no significant signs of any kind of dirt or something,
5. Pressing ctrl + alt + F11 doesn't do anything.

WHAT DO ?!

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps another test. open notepad, do ctrl-p does a print dialog box appear or not? i'd consider booting another os off usb and trying some control-key shortcut there..if it is a hardware issue then hmm

Comment: Ctrl-p does not do anything, Ctrl keys won't work in Linux either.

Comment: Can it actually be that both control keys stop working the same instant ? Is it possible that Asus has built in a feature that switches off both keys for some crazy purpose ?

Comment: I don't know. Some ideas. Try plugging a keyboard in.. Try mapping a key to ctrl. Try calling asus. Try http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/